# Disable Right Click in Popup Window

Tags: c#, asp.net, treeview

how should I disable the right click in Popup Window. I dont want the user to save or print the document in the Popup Window. Here is my interface [Interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HnHri.png)

Here is my aspx.cs code under TreeView1_SelectedNodeChanged

```html
 protected void TreeView1_SelectedNodeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Session["loggedUserID"] == null && Session["loggedRoleID"] == null)
        {
            Response.Redirect("~/Login.aspx");
        }


        else
        {
            if (TreeView1.SelectedNode.Parent == null)
            {

                ltEmbed.Visible = false;
            }

            else
            {
                ltEmbed.Visible = true;

                string Text = TreeView1.SelectedNode.Text.ToString();
               

                int loggedUserID = Convert.ToInt32(Session["loggedUserID"]);
                List<BOL.UserInfo> userslist = new UserInfos().List();
                BOL.UserInfo loggeduser = userslist.Where(x => x.UserID == loggedUserID).FirstOrDefault();
            
                BOL.DMS getdetail = new DMSS().GET_FILE(loggeduser.SUBSIDIARY_CD, Text);
                string FILE_NAME = getdetail.F_NAME;
                string FILE_PATH = getdetail.MAIN;
             
                
                 string url = String.Format(ResolveUrl(FILE_PATH));
 
                 string script = "window.open('" + url + "', '_blank','popup_window','width=700,height=600,left=100,top=100,resizable=false,oncontextmenu= return false');";
                 ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "popUp", script, true);

                     
            }





        }


    }
```

Thank you.

Comment: Why do you want to do that? It is my browser and as a user I should have control over my options or I will not be happy with your site.

Comment: @CodingYoshi, This pop up window is to display the controlled document to users. They cant print or save them.